# mySQL Another combination query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a couple of statements that I can't seem to understand how to combine.

Right now, my code looks like this:

```
if(!$question && $filter){
    $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mbr_qa_questions WHERE q_tags RLIKE '[[:<:]]" . $filter . "[[:>:]]' ORDER BY q_id ASC LIMIT $start, 1 ");
} else if($question && !$filter){
    $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mbr_qa_questions WHERE MATCH (q_title, q_description, q_tags) AGAINST ('$question') ORDER BY q_id ASC LIMIT $start, 1 ");
} else if($question && $filter){
    //NEED A COMBINED QUERY OF THE FIRST TWO HERE.
} else {
    $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mbr_qa_questions ORDER BY q_id ASC LIMIT $start, 1");
}
```

I have the few columns (`q_title, q_description, q_tags`) indexed, though I'm not sure any of these statements are efficient enough.

*Long story short*, I need this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM mbr_qa_questions WHERE q_tags RLIKE '[[:<:]]" . $filter . "[[:>:]]' ORDER BY q_id ASC LIMIT $start, 1
```

and this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM mbr_qa_questions WHERE MATCH (q_title, q_description, q_tags) AGAINST ('$question') ORDER BY q_id ASC LIMIT $start, 1
```

combined into a single statement.  Also, if you're so inclined, please tell me how inefficient this is and possibly suggest a better way?

Comment: If your if() construction makes no sense. The first two clauses are identical, boiling down to `if (a) else if (a) else if (b) else`. As for combinging the queries, just tie the two clauses together with `AND` or `OR`... it's not rocket science.

Comment: @MarcB Sorry, that was a hasty edit to make this easier to read.  That is fixed and thank you.  I can just do that?  Just add "AND" to the end of one statement and paste the other statement on the end of it??

Comment: `WHERE clause1 AND clause2` or whatever. Don't do something silly like `WHERE clause AND WHERE clause2`. that's a syntax error.

Comment: to combine SQL statements you can use UNION. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-union-keyword.htm

Comment: Thank you all.  I have another requirement that I won't burden you with on this question, though I now need to figure out how to find the `$question`s and use the `$filter`s to cut down the number of questions.  Right now, with your suggestions it adds the filters to the questions.  I know I did not specify this, so I will struggle a bit more before asking a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the AND operator

```
if(!$question && $filter){
    $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mbr_qa_questions WHERE q_tags RLIKE '[[:<:]]" . $filter . "[[:>:]]' ORDER BY q_id ASC LIMIT $start, 1 ");
} else if($question && !$filter){
    $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mbr_qa_questions WHERE MATCH (q_title, q_description, q_tags) AGAINST ('$question') ORDER BY q_id ASC LIMIT $start, 1 ");
} else if($question && $filter){
    //combined using AND 
    $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mbr_qa_questions WHERE MATCH (q_title, q_description, q_tags) AGAINST ('$question') AND q_tags RLIKE '[[:<:]]" . $filter . "[[:>:]]' ORDER BY q_id ASC LIMIT $start,     1 ");
} else {
    $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mbr_qa_questions ORDER BY q_id ASC LIMIT $start, 1");
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This does the trick, though now I have to figure out how to pull ONLY the information that has the question and then filter out those results.  Right now, it's adding both question and result. I know I did not add this into my original question but if you know of a way, that would be great.  Otherwise, I'll play around and possibly ask another question